# Interdependent caches invalidation and memory management

Tags: caching, architecture, memory-leaks, invalidation

I am working on a Java project which makes heavy use of Observer pattern to make sure every data object state is up to date. I grew tired of maintaining this mess and am trying to implement a solution that would decouple the terrors of Observer pattern from my precious data objects.

I was able to abstract away the details of this project to say that the problem I am trying to solve is following:

> There exists a set of objects representing expressions, each of which can depend on the values of other expressions.
>
> The following two operations are required:
>
> **eval(): Retrieve the value of a given expression**
>
> This operation should return the up to date value of the expression which would be returned if all the expression dependencies would re re-evaluated right now. However, no expression should be evaluated more than once unless its cache is invalidated by the second operation:
>
> **update(): Modify a given expression**
>
> This operation invalidates the cache for the expression and for all the currently cached expressions that depend on it directly or transitively.
>
> In addition, some convenient memory-leak-free way to manage lifetime of the expressions is required.

Desired usage example in pseudo-code:

```
Expression a = variable(1);
Expression b = variable(3);
Expression s = sum(a,b);
assert(4 == eval(s));    // causes evaluation of expressions a, b and s
assert(4 == eval(s));    // does not cause any evaluations,
                         //     the result should be taken from cache
setValue(a,2);           // contains update() internally, 
                         //     invalidating caches for a and s
assert(5 == eval(s));    // causes evaluation of a and s
```

OK, the functional part is over, here goes the memory management part.

There must be some easy way for the developer to manage the expression graph. Ideally, the allocation should be done with `new Sum(a,b)`, developer should have the freedom to pass around expression instances as he likes, without much knowledge about cache, and deallocation should happen automatically with no effort from the developer side.

And there must not be any memory leaks. That is when an expression is deallocated, there must not be anything left in the memory associated with it. For example, if observer pattern is to be used for invalidation, the expression must be removed from all observer lists.

The question is:

**What would be your approach to implementing this in your favourite language?**

Non-garbage-collected and functional languages are welcome too, especially functional because I don't understand how to approach this problem in pure functional at all.

The best solution from my point of view would be the one with the least possibility of developer error.

I am intentionally not posting my current implementation details yet because I think I have found a fundamental flaw in my implementation and I don't see any way around it. I will post it later though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested (which nobody probably is anyway), I had to lay off the global cache idea and solved the problem by making my `Expression`s self-caching.

I implemented all the logic in a base class called `ExpressionBase`.

The solution includes the following:

- An expression contains a list of weak references to its dependants and notifies them on change. This way there are no memory leaks and no need to unsubscribe.
- During an expression evaluation it automatically detects dependencies in a way similar to described in my previous answer and subscribes to them.
- The list of dependencies is kept to prevent too early garbage-collection of intermediate expressions (the `SumProxyExpression` case from my previous answer). This way every weak reference has its reverse strong counterpart so that chains of weak references are not broken by GC unless these chains lead nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here I will try to explain my approach to the problem using the Java language.

Everything will be explained on an example of SumExpression - the expression used to add the results of two other expressions together.

### User code

I started with the most straightforward approach - the Observer pattern. Every expression would be listening to its dependencies for cache invalidation. Here is the version of SumExpression implemented in this way:

```
public class SumExpression implements Expression<Integer> {
    private final Expression<Integer> a;
    private final Expression<Integer> b;

    Integer value;
    private Listener invalidator = new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void changed() {
            invalidate();
        }
    };
    
    public SumExpression(SimpleVariable<Integer> a, SimpleVariable<Integer> b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        a.listeners().addListener(invalidator);// don't forget to call it!
        b.listeners().addListener(invalidator);
    }
    
    public Integer getValue()
    {
        validate();
        return value;
    }
    
    private void validate() {
        if(value == null)
            value = evaluate;
    }

    private void evaluate() {
        value = null;
    }
    
    public void dispose() { // USER, DON'T FORGET TO CALL IT!!!
        a.removeListener(invalidator);
        b.removeListener(invalidator);
    }

    ListenerCollection listeners = new ListenerCollection();
    
    @Override
    public void addListener(Listener l) {
        listeners.addListener(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(Listener l) {
        listeners.removeListener(l);
    }
}
```

However, there is a whole lot of places where it can go wrong, and something as simple as addition of two numbers should be much more simple. So, I've decoupled the logic from caching in the following way:

```
public class SumExpression implements Expression<Integer> {
    private final Expression<Integer> a;
    private final Expression<Integer> b;

    public SumExpression(Expression<Integer> a, Expression<Integer> b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    public Integer evaluate(EvaluationContext context)
    {
        return context.getValue(a)+context.getValue(b);
    }
}
```

Much simpler, huh? Note that here `EvaluationContext`'s responsibility is twofold: it retrieves the values from cache and collects the list of dependencies between the `SumExpression` and expressions `a` and `b`.

### Core code

Next, I provided `EvaluationContext` by the global caching class which stores the cached data in a structure similar to `WeakHashMap<Expression, Object>`, and the dependency graph data in a DAG with nodes being of type `WeakReference<Expression>`.

Here is my implementation of **eval** and **update**:

```
public <T1> T1 eval(final Expression<T1> expression)
{
    Weak weak = weaken(expression);
    T1 result = (T1) cache.get(weak);
    if(result == null) {
        result = expression.evaluate(new EvaluationContext()
        {
            @Override
            public <T2> T2 getValue(Expression<T2> dependency) {
                registerDependency(expression, dependency);
                return eval(dependency);
            }
        });
        cache.put(weak, result);
    }
    return result;
}

public void update(Expression<?> ex) {
    changed(weaken(ex));
}

public void changed(Weak weak) {
    cache.remove(weak);
    
    dependencies.removeOutgoingArcs(weak);
    for(Weak dependant : new ArrayList<Weak>(dependencies.getIncoming(weak))) {
        changed(dependant);
    }
}
```

When my cache manager is asked for an object it first checks in cache. If there is no value in the cache it asks the expression to evaluate. The expression then asks the cache manager to resolve its dependencies by calling getValue() method. This creates an arc in the dependency graph. This graph is later used for cache invalidation.

When an expression is invalidated, the dependency graph is explored and all the dependent caches are invalidated.

Cache and dependency graph clean-up is performed as soon as the garbage collector notifies us (through ReferenceQueue) about the death of some expression objects.

Everything mostly works as it should. However, there are a few tricky cases.

### Tricky cases

First case is a hanging intermediate dependency. Suppose we have the following class:

```
class SumProxyExpression implements Expression<Integer> {
    private final Expression<Integer> a;
    private final Expression<Integer> b;

    public SumProxyExpression(Expression<Integer> a, Expression<Integer> b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer evaluate(EvaluationContext context) {
        Expression<Integer> s = new SumExpression(a, b);
        return context.getValue(s);
    }
}
```

If we create an instance of `c=SumProxyExpression(a,b)` and change the value for `a` later we would want the `c` to change its value as well. However, if the intermediate `SumExpression` is already garbage-collected, this may not happen. To combat this, I do not delete nodes from the dependency graph unless they are leaf nodes (have only incoming or only outgoing arcs).

The other case, which I don't know how to solve, is the following:

```
class SelfReferencingExpression implements Expression<List<?>> {
    class Result extends ArrayList<Integer> {
    }

    @Override
    public List<?> evaluate(EvaluationContext resolver) {
        return new Result();
    }
}
```

If I cache the result of such an expression, it will never get garbage-collected because I keep hard references to cached values (`Result`), and it has a reference to a containing class (the expression), so the expression is always reachable, but could never be used.

This is a memory leak and I have no idea how to eliminate it. Telling user to never have such a reference is possible, but very dangerous, so I would like to find a better solution.

### Alternative solutions

I also thought about implementing it with inheritance from a common self-caching expression class instead of holding everything in a global cache. This solution would solve the last test case (SelfReferencingExpression), but would fail with the first one (SumProxyExpression).